# Different CSS displayed between Dev environment and Production environment for website with same code

Tags: css, wordpress

For the following website that I have made: ifrs.site (WordPress site with custom theme, if that's important), there is an overlap of content by the footer when the browser window is not maximised on desktop, or when viewed on mobile. I fixed this overlap issue in the dev environment, but the live website with the same CSS code as the dev website ends up with a worse overlap.

What is the cause in discrepancy? You can see the differences in code at this github repo: https://github.com/keg504/IFRS-Website-theme-files, in the 2 branches dev-files and master. What is on master is what is used on the site currently.

I'm using Local by Flywheel for the dev environment on Windows 10, and the CSS is run using a webpack configuration on nodejs.

**Edit:** As Aliqua has requested, I've added the wp_enqueue_style function I'm calling to load the CSS: `wp_enqueue_style('our-main-styles', get_theme_file_uri('/bundled-assets/styles.ba56d060f11656536bc3.css'));`

The part between styles...css changes whenever npm run build is run in the command line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on your design/setup the css could have attached in the source code a `?ver=1.0.0` or similar. Which means if you have made changes but not updated the version it is still recalling the original file from the cache.

Some developers overcome this by setting the `enqueue_script()` version part of the array to a `date()` (including time with hour-min-sec) function. This will mean that everytime the page is refreshed the version is different and it wont recall older versions of the css from the cache.

Search your code for the enqueue script line for the css in question and see if you can set date() to the version value.

Refer to https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php for more information.

Update:
Based on your update, you could replace it with something like this.

```
wp_enqueue_style( 'our-main-styles',
    get_theme_file_uri('/bundled-assets/styles.ba56d060f11656536bc3.css'),
    array( $parent_style ), // remove if there is no parent style
    date("His")
);
```

Reference wp_enqueue_style - https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_style/

Final Thoughts:
Please note, that this answer may in fact not be the actual solution as much as I have tried to identify your issue. Please refer to https://developer.wordpress.org/ to familiarise yourself with the introductory information in relation to wordpress development. If you are going to want to do more changes to your wordpress CMS, you will need a basic understanding of how to make changes. Please focus some of your research to plugin creation, working with child themes, and how to make your own custom functions. Then you will be able to write better questions, and be able to action the answers in the future.

Best of luck with your development.

Comment: So I have a call to wp_enqueue_style in my functions.php file. Does that mean I should add the new CSS and then change the versioning in the enqueue script call? I am using bundled scripts from nodejs, so in the dev environment the name of the CSS file being called keeps changing whenever npm run dev is run

Comment: Thanks, I know you're putting me on the right track, but I don't know how to use the information effectively yet without more information. I've added it as you asked

Comment: Thanks, I think you've answered my question. I didn't realise that enqueue styles would be the problem because of the local nodejs build, as the styling just worked when the site went live.
Out of curiosity, how could I have phrased/written my question better?

Comment: Have a look at the support section of stackoverflow - https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking and also just look at other questions asked here with good responses. You'll pick it up quickly. Happy coding! :)